# What is the colon meaning in the qw declaration?

Tags: perl

I am reading about `Log4Perl` from `perl.com`
In the tutorial it says:  `use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);`

What is the `:` in front of `easy`? Is it some kind of special syntax?

Comment: Just wondering if that could be a *vim close file* tic (:

Answer (score 11):

It is special syntax, for [Specialised Import Lists](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html#Specialised-Import-Lists), specifically for export tags.

Here's the example exporter part of a module from that documentation

```
@EXPORT      = qw(A1 A2 A3 A4 A5);
@EXPORT_OK   = qw(B1 B2 B3 B4 B5);
%EXPORT_TAGS = (T1 => [qw(A1 A2 B1 B2)], T2 => [qw(A1 A2 B3 B4)]);
```

A user of that module could say:

```
use Module qw(:DEFAULT :T2);
```

to import all of the names from the default set (`@EXPORT`) plus the ones defined in the `T2` set.

***Unless...***

the package in question overloads the `import` sub and does whatever it wants with the option, which is what this package seems to do according to   [amesee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16759871/635608).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I honestly didn't know about this convention in Export. All this time I thought it was an unwritten convention that everyone just followed.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a special perl syntax. It's just some prefix determined by the author that makes this string look more like a value for configuration. You can see for yourself in the [import definition](https://github.com/mschilli/log4perl/blob/master/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm#L87). It just looks for the existence of a value in a hash with the key of `:easy`. Just a string consisting of characters ':', 'e', 'a', 's', 'y'.

Comment: Log4perl uses a custom `import` method, but the `:tag` format is a convention established by the standard [Exporter](https://metacpan.org/module/Exporter) module.

Comment: @friedo Thanks for pointing this out. I honestly didn't know about that api in Export. All this time I thought it was just some unwritten convention that everyone just followed. Very interesting.